# Custom Principal with OAuth2 in existing form login application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to add OAuth2 login to an existing form login application. So far I've added the required configuration to get Google auth working and the goal is to enable existing username/password users (or new users) to login both ways.

All my controllers rely on my `UserDetails` implementation:

```java
public class User implements UserDetails {
  
  private Long id;
  private String email;
  private String password;

  private String googleAccessToken;

  // ...
```

And I can get the logged user in controllers like this:

```java
@GetMapping
public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model) {
```

So what I've done is to implement my custom `OAuth2UserService` to fetch the existing user from the database but I can't find the way to set the `User` as the principal.

In previous versions of the OAuth2 integration it seemed to exist a simpler solution based on `PrincipalExtractor` but it is no longer available.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2UserDetailsService implements OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> {

  private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

  @Override
  public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
    final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();
    User user;

    // Delegate to the default implementation for loading a user
    OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

    switch (userRequest.getClientRegistration().getClientName()) {
      case "google":
        user = usersRepository.findOneByGoogleAccessToken(userRequest.getAccessToken());
        break;
      default:
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error("invalid_token"));
    }

    // here I should return my user principal
    return new DefaultOidcUser(null, null);
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this returning an instance of `OidcUser`:

```java
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails, OidcUser {
  // ...
}
```

And in the `OAuth2UserService`:

```java
@Override
public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
  final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();
  User user;

  // Delegate to the default implementation for loading a user
  OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

  // ...
  return new UserPrincipal(user, oidcUser);
}
```